# StimulSoft Report Viewer Not Working In IP Valid With Port 8818

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I Use StimulSoft Ver:2015.2  in my MVC Web Application 
I Use This Code In My View :

```
@Html.Stimulsoft().RenderMvcViewerScripts();
<div>
    @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewerFx(options: new StiMvcViewerFxOptions
    {
        Theme = StiThemeFx.Office2013,
        Actions =
        {
            GetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshotForPeriodic",

            // ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent",
            //Interaction = "Interaction",
            //DesignReport = "GetReportTemplate"
        },
        Appearance =
        {

        },
        Toolbar =
        {

            ShowParametersButton = true
        }
    })
</div>
```

When I run the application it works correct in LocalNetwork but when I use microtech to redirect my Valid Ip To My Local and I run the web site from valid ip it gots error of:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Infact `GetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshotForPeriodic"`,not find on server with port 8818 or any other port
how can I redirect to Getreportsnapshot with same ip and port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which file should I insert this code?

You should use the UseRelativeUrls option if you change the server.

```
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewerFx(options: new StiMvcViewerFxOptions
{
    Server =
    {
         UseRelativeUrls = true
    }
```